# 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: pyinstaller

I have created exe of python file using pyinstaller.From that file I am calling another python script.when I run my project on clean VM where python is not installed I am getting error like python is not recognised

```
import subprocess
import time
import sys
import os
print ("Hello")
python_path = "python"
args = [python_path,'test.py']
print(args)
subprocess.Popen(args)
time.sleep(100)
```

Where pyinstaller will look for python.When exe is frozen I found only python35.dll.How can i run python script from exe without installing python.

Answer (score 1):

Download a standalone python package like WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.3 (This does not require to be installed with admin rights). You can unzip the files to a preferred directory.

From the WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.3 folder, you can copy the contents of the python source code folder (Eg : python-2.7.10.amd64, in this case) to the directory where you have placed exe file created using pyinstaller.

The python-2.7.10.amd64 (In this case) has the python.exe and other dependency files required for the subprocess call to run.